# How to run an animation once another ends?

Tags: animation

I want to run an animation with `Animate`after another ends, not at same time. 
This is my code:[image]

Its possible run r from 5 to 2 and, later, run s rom 2 to 0?

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
Animate[Plot[Evaluate@If[r >= 2, Sqrt[x^2 + (1 - r/2) E^(r/2)], 
{Sqrt[x^2], Sqrt[x^2 + (1 - r/2) E^(r/2)]}], {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {0, 3}}], {r, 5, 0}]
```

[image]